# How do I get the page URL of a wiki page with mwclient?

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mwclient

I'm using [mwclient](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient) and I want to get the URL of the page loaded.

```
import mwclient
site = mwclient.Site('fr.wikipedia.org')
page = site.Pages['Curling aux Jeux olympiques de 2022']
```

Is it possible to get the url of the page? ⇒ 'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curling_aux_Jeux_olympiques_de_2022'

Comment: check this [doc](https://mwclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/page.html) it's maybe helpful

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documented features that do this. You could, of course, query the URL from the wiki itself, but I think that's not what you want, correct?

Comment: Yes indeed, that's not what I want.
I've given up on this library. I use [mediawiki](https://github.com/barrust/mediawiki)  which offers more functionality.